# unable to restart the Gps

Tags: android, gps, broadcastreceiver, restart

Hai am trying to stop and Start the Gps location.when my Application is Start the Gps is Started.In my broadCast receiver i need to stop the gps and again start it.But  my Gps is not Stopped .Anybody please rectify help me.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    Log.i("ConnTest",locationManager.toString());
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

// Initialize the location fields
if (location != null) {
    System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
    float lat = (float) (location.getLatitude());
    float lng = (float) (location.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    final   double  a=(int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
 final  double  b=(int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
str = Double.toString(a);
str2=Double.toString(b);

} else {
    latituteField.setText("provider not available");
    longitudeField.setText("provider not available");
}

    txtNetworkInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtNetworkInfo);

    receiver = new ConnectivityReceiver();

            registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));


}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,1000, 1, this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            provider, 
            MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
            MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
            this
    );
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float lat = (float) (location.getLatitude());
    float lng = (float) (location.getLongitude());
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));


}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disenabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
protected void Display(Cursor c) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "rowid: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
     "Latitude: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" + "Longitude: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG, 0).show();    
}

@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);

            super.onDestroy();
    }

private String getNetworkStateString(NetworkInfo.State state){
    String stateString = "Unknown";

    switch(state)
    {
            case CONNECTED:         stateString = "Connected";break;
            case CONNECTING:        stateString = "Connecting";break;
            case DISCONNECTED:      stateString = "Disconnected"; break;
            case DISCONNECTING:     stateString = "Disconnecting";break;
            case SUSPENDED:         stateString = "Suspended";  break;
            default:                        stateString = "Unknown";break;
    }

    return stateString;
}

    private class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

            private Timer mTimer;
            private TimerTask mTimerTask;

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

                    if(null != info)
                    {
                            String state = getNetworkStateString(info.getState());
                            if(state.equals("Connected")){
                                mTimer = new Timer();
                                mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                                                stop();
                                            }
                                        });

                                   }
                                };
                                mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTimerTask,180000,180000);
                            }


                            }
            }   
                    }

            }
    private void stop() {
        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                          locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    }
                });

           }
        };
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTimerTask,180000,180000);

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be disabling the updates when onPause() is called.  When you press back your gps isn't disabled?  is there maybe another app or service running that is using GPS?

Comment: No only one Application is running

Comment: when you press back it doesn't disable the GPS?  And also are you running any services?